# Expected value and variance of loss from casino playing

Tags: statistics

Let A and B be 2 independent random variables, that represents how much you win from two different games at a casino. It costs 10\$ to bet on A and 40\$ to bet on B.

$E(A) = 9$, $\sqrt{V(A)} = 3$

$E(B) = 36$, $\sqrt{V(B)} = 10$

If you play 3 times at A and 2 times at B, calculate the expected value and std of total loss.

How I've tried to solve it:

$ X = 3A + 2B$

$Loss = 110 - X = 110 - (3A + 2B)$

My thinking is that, we bet 110\$ and as A and B give us how much we win, the difference should indicate loss (or win if it's negative)

$E(Loss) = 110 - 3E(A) - 2E(B) = 11$

So far so good, this is the correct answer according to the book, but I don't get it right for the std/variance:

$V(loss) = V(110 - X) = V(X) = V(3A + 2B) = 9V(A) + 4V(B) = 9\cdot9 + 4\cdot100 = 481$

This is not the correct answer according to the book, where does my logic break?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Simple question, what am I doing wrong?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I understand, $3A + 2B$ is not correct as every play is a different random variable, therefore $Loss = 110 - (A_1 + A_2 + A_3) - (B_1 + B_2)$